# template_group and template_name not matching segment_1 and segment_2

Tags: templates, segments, ee3

Using EE 3.0.5

http://example.com/documentation/style_guide

template_group: documentation
template_name: index

segment_1: documentation
segment_2: style_guide

The style_guide template is not displaying.. it's reverting to the index template.

I can't figure out what would cause segment_2 to not be the template_name

Only index and 1 other template in the template_group displays correctly. All others revert to index.

Haven't modified template routes.

.htaccess removes index.php per documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There was a recent bug for template permissions. Newly created templates couldn't be viewed by anyone, and while this has been fixed in recent versions it's still true for duplicated templates. Go into your template manager and check access permissions for your groups. Temporarily working as Superadmin should work, too.

Comment: Glad to hear it :)